# What spike is this? Identifying some utensils

Tags: equipment, utensils

I moved into a new home and found these spikes left behind in different drawers in the kitchen. I assume they are for cooking, but they are not items that I have come across in my limited culinary experience. Can you help me identify them and maybe suggest a recipe that uses them?

[image: Mystery spikes]

In the background is a large spike-stand.

The foreground, is a bunch of six individual spikes with two 90 degree bends, and a sharp point on the long side.

They may have been supplied with the oven (gas stove, electric oven) or the combination microwave/grill, or maybe have nothing to do with them at all (or cooking in general) and may have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have a definitive answer. I found a manual to the combination microwave oven, which is a Samsung C108STBC or similar.

The accessories to this oven (which can grill and/or microwave) include:

- a roasting spit (also referred to as "roasting stand") which is the larger spike.

  > The roasting spit is a convenient way of barbecuing a chicken, as the meat does not have to be turned over. It can be used for grill combination cooking.
- the skewers that fit into a plastic "coupler" that I found in another cupboard drawer (it looks a little like a cotton reel and I would have never picked it as something to be put in an oven). Together, the skewers are mounted vertically in a circle to form a "multi-spit".

  > Using the multi-spit with 6 kebab skewers you can easily barbecue meat, poultry, fish, vegetables (like onions, peppers or courgettes) and fruit which have been cut into pieces.

Comment: At first I wondered how the roasting stand was supposed to work, then I realized the oven (being a microwave combo) likely has a turntable. Skewer chicken on spit, place in center of turntable, presto, chicken rotates for even roasting!

Answer (score 10):

The spike stand in the background looks like a ticket puncher that you'd see in a cafe. As in, after you pay your ticket, the staff member pokes it through the spike to collect them all.

[image: Example of receipt spike]

Comment: It turns out to just be coincidentally visually similar. See my answer.

Answer (score 8):

They Z shapes look like roasting spikes (or skewers)

Used for odd shaped birds and meat cuts to make suitable for even roasting, especially on a spit-roast (rotating roast machine)

The Z shapes spikes are used to hold out a flap, or to hold two parts together. The bend is used to lock it in place against another part of the meat, or against another spike

The spike with the stand is most likely a receipt spike, though I have seen similar things used to hold roasts up of the tray to stop "soggy bottoms", and to let the fat drain off

Comment: I have been googling for images of roasting skewers, and haven't found anything that looks similar.

Answer (score 1):

My mother used small skewers in baking potatoes, although not shaped like yours. (The metal supposedly conducted heat into the potatao centers to speed baking. I was and remain skeptical of the efficacy of this) 
I agree that the single unit looks like an order spike.

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a divider stands for your bowls inside the drawers.

Comment: Can you provide an example link, so we know what you are referring to?